# Secure Google API key in an API deployed on docker and Google cloud

Tags: python, docker, security, google-cloud-platform

I'm looking to deploy an API as part of a mobile application in which I'm using a google service via an API key, but I can't find any resources to secure it effectively.

The only solution I've found is to put the key in an env file, but is that really enough?
It would look like this:

```
GOOGLE_API_KEY="my_api_key" (in an environment file)
```

Then

```
import os 
api_key = os.environ.get('GOOGLE_API_KEY')
```

Does anyone have any insights?

Comment: Where the API is deployed? On Google Cloud? On which service?

Comment: Yes the api is deployed on google cloud

Comment: On which service?

Comment: Cloud Run for a serverless api

Comment: In that case the solution is easy: put your API (i.e. the secret) in secret manager, and then load it as env var in Cloud Run. https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/services/secrets